# How to use proportions with lookup tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

The Min_Prop_of_As shows the minimum proportion of undergraduate students receiving a percentage grade of >=80. I only want to use the undergrad grades in cells `C2:C15`. How do I write a `VLOOKUP` statement for cell `G14`?

I am not really sure how I can use the proportion to determine the level of class performance so I can use it with the lookup table? For example, if the proportion of undergraduate students receiving a percentage grade of >=80 is 0.37, then the class will have a Good level of class performance.

Would something like this work?

```
=VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C15, >=80, B2:B15, "UGRD") / (B2:B15,"UGRD"),F9:G12,2)
```

Image of the worksheet:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(G9:G12,MATCH(COUNTIF(C2:C15,">=80")/COUNTA(C2:C15),F9:F12,1))
```

`COUNTIF(C2:C15,">=80")/COUNTA(C2:C15)` will determine the ratio of students with a score of 80 or more, this value is then used to `MATCH` the ones in `F9:F12` and return the corresponding values in `G9:G12` using `INDEX`

Comment: Good answer. Note that this is an appearance of the less-common use case to use the inexact match argument "1" in the INDEX function, because you want to bring back the matching tier from the Class Performance lookup table, not find the exact-match value.